# If dX=dZ, does that mean that X(t)=Z(t)

Tags: stochastic-processes

For two stochastic processes: X(t), Z(t). If dX=dZ, does that mean that X(t)=Z(t). My intuition says yes, but I cant prove it.

Comment: If you're not going to show any working for a textbook style problem, you ought to at least attempt explain some kind of basis for the source of such an intuition. That is, why do you think this would make sense?

Answer (score 3):

No. Think of starting point $X(0)\ne Z(0)$.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/127015)

Comment: (+1) @mdewey In what sense would this not be an answer?

Comment: I don't know what the OP means by dX=dZ.  If this a stochastic differential?  If we take it to be a single realization of both processes maybe we could be dealing with ordinary calculus in which case X(t) and Z(t) would only differ by a constant of integration.  Of course this is an answer.  But is it a solution to the problem the OP intended?

Comment: @MichaelChernick my answer would be the same for both stochastic and leibnitz calculus.

Comment: @whuber i felt the questioner was struggling and a fuller answer might have been more helpful.